# Convert nested dict/json to a django ORM model, without hard coding the data structure

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I want to import data from json files into my django db. The json contains nested objects.

Current steps are:

1. Set up my django object models to match the json schema (done manually - see `models.py` file below)
2. Import json file into python dict using `mydict = json.loads(file.read())` (done)
3. **Convert dict to django models** (done - but solution is not pretty)

**Is there a way I can convert my nested dict into django models (i.e. step 3) without hard-coding the data structure into the logic?**

Bonus points for automatically generating the django models (i.e. the `models.py` file) based on an example json file.

**Thanks in advance!**

## How I'm currently doing it

Step 3 is easy if the dict does not contain any nested dicts - just [construct a new object from the dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34826069/2512919) i.e. `MyModel.objects.create(**mydict)` or [use django fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475240/django-import-reformat-json-into-model).

However, because my json/dict contains nested objects, I'm currently doing step 3 like this:

```
# read the json file into a python dict
d = json.loads(myfile.read())

# construct top-level object using the top-level dict
# (excluding nested lists of dicts called 'judges' and 'contestants')
c = Contest.objects.create(**{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k not in ('judges', 'contestants')})

# construct nested objects using the nested dicts
for judge in d['judges']:
    c.judge_set.create(**judge)
for contestant in d['contestants']:
    ct = c.contestant_set.create(**{k:v for k,v in contestant.items() if k not in ('singers', 'songs')})
    # all contestants sing songs
    for song in contestant['songs']:
        ct.song_set.create(**song)
    # not all contestants have a list of singers
    if 'singers' in contestant:
        for singer in contestant['singers']:
            ct.singer_set.create(**singer)
```

This works, but requires the data structure to be hard coded into the logic:

- Need to hard code the names of the nested dicts to exclude when calling `create()` (if you try to pass a nested dict to `create()` it throws a `TypeError`). I thought about instead doing `**{k:v for k,v in contestant.items() if not hasattr(v, 'pop')}` to exclude lists and dicts, but I suspect that won't work 100% of the time.
- Need to hard code logic to iteratively create the nested objects
- Need to hard code logic to deal with nested objects that are not always present

## Data structures

example json looks like this:

```
{
  "assoc": "THE BRITISH ASSOCIATION OF BARBERSHOP SINGERS",
  "contest": "QUARTET FINAL (NATIONAL STREAM)",
  "location": "CHELTENHAM",
  "year": "2007/08",
  "date": "25/05/2008",
  "type": "quartet final",
  "filename": "BABS/2008QF.pdf"
  "judges": [
    {"cat": "m", "name": "Rod"},
    {"cat": "m", "name": "Bob"},
    {"cat": "p", "name": "Pat"},
    {"cat": "p", "name": "Bob"},
    {"cat": "s", "name": "Mark"},
    {"cat": "s", "name": "Barry"},
    {"cat": "a", "name": "Phil"}
  ],
  "contestants": [
    {
      "prev_tot_score": "1393",
      "tot_score": "2774",
      "rank_m": "1",
      "rank_s": "1",
      "rank_p": "1",
      "rank": "1", "name": "Monkey Magic",
      "pc_score": "77.1",
      "songs": [
        {"title": "Undecided Medley","m": "234","s": "226","p": "241"},
        {"title": "What Kind Of Fool Am I","m": "232","s": "230","p": "230"},
        {"title": "Previous","m": "465","s": "462","p": "454"}
      ],
      "singers": [
        {"part": "tenor","name": "Alan"},
        {"part": "lead","name": "Zac"},
        {"part": "bari","name": "Joe"},
        {"part": "bass","name": "Duncan"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "prev_tot_score": "1342",
      "tot_score": "2690",
      "rank_m": "2",
      "rank_s": "2",
      "rank_p": "2",
      "rank": "2", "name": "Evolution",
      "pc_score": "74.7",
      "songs": [
        {"title": "It's Impossible","m": "224","s": "225","p": "218"},
        {"title": "Come Fly With Me","m": "225","s": "222","p": "228"},
        {"title": "Previous","m": "448","s": "453","p": "447"}
      ],
      "singers": [
        {"part": "tenor","name": "Tony"},
        {"part": "lead","name": "Michael"},
        {"part": "bari","name": "Geoff"},
        {"part": "bass","name": "Stuart"}
      ]
    },
  ],
}
```

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Contest(models.Model):
    assoc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Judge(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    cat = models.CharField('Category', max_length=2)


class Contestant(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tot_score = models.IntegerField('Total Score')
    rank_m = models.IntegerField()
    rank_s = models.IntegerField()
    rank_p = models.IntegerField()
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    pc_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)
    # optional fields
    director = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    prev_tot_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class Song(models.Model):
    contestant = models.ForeignKey(Contestant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    m = models.IntegerField('Music')
    s = models.IntegerField('Singing')
    p = models.IntegerField('Performance')

class Singer(models.Model):
    contestant = models.ForeignKey(Contestant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    part = models.CharField('Category', max_length=5)
```

Comment: By definition, the object model contains the description of your data model. If you don't know how your data is structured, I highly doubt you can model it. Your best bet would probably be to extract the nested data to a separate model using an ID and then importing them by matching that ID, but that's going to be quite a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

You could browse the json object recursively and use a key to class mapping to instantiate your models dynamically. Here's an **idea** (not a working solution!):

```
 key_model = {
        "contestants": Contestant,
        "singers": Singer
 }

 def make_sub_model(parent, model, vals):
    for v in vals:
       child = create_model(model, v)
       parent.add_child(child) # or whatever it is with Django Models

def create_model(model, obj):
    # model should be the class and obj a dict

    # take care of the top lvl object
    to_process = [] # store nest models
    parent = {} # store parent attributes
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, list): # you probably want dict as well
            to_process.append((k, v))
        else:
           parent[k] = v

    parent_obj = model.create(**parent)
    # now process the chidlrend
    for k, v in to_process:
        make_sub_model(parent_obj, key_model[k], v)

    return parent_obj
```

But in the end, I would **discourage this** because you are using a Schema based storage (SQL) so your code should enforce that the input matches your schema (you can't handle anything different on the fly anyway). If you don't care about having a schema at all go for a No-SQL solution and you won't have this problem. Or a hybrid like PostgresSQL.